# How to mount a directory inside a fs instead of the whole fs?

Tags: filesystem, mount, ntfs, fstab

I've got an NTFS partition which I never need as a whole. When using it from Ubuntu I only need a specific directory of it which I like to have mounted into a dedicated directory under my Linux FS root. Can I specify it in fstab?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly. You still have to mount the filesystem of the partition but if you dont want it to show up as a drive in nautilus, mount it to somewhere in `/mnt/`

From there you can do a further bind-mount in `/etc/fstab` to mount the specific directory you want in a place where you want it, eg:

```
/mnt/windows/dir-you-want-to-mount    /media/mydir    bind
```

Comment: Given he needs to mount the whole partition somewhere in the fs, wouldnt a symlink pointing from `/mnt/somedir` to `/media/mydir` be much better than a 2nd fstab entry?

Comment: @oli Is 'bind' a type of mount? I am looking for a resource to search how to understand those mounting types but I don't know what keyword I should be searching for exactly, could you please provide me with some guidelines to start?, Thanks.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Yeah, it's a simple in-kernel mapping between two already-mounted places. The documentation for bind mounts is in `man mount` (search for "bind" and you'll see it). It's not that thorough but it's quite a simple method.